# What will cause when collision check sampling rate set too low?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [moveit wizard tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#Pre-requisites).

If I only set collision check sampling rate at 1000, what bad situation will happen?

Is PR2 maybe more possible to in collision when executing a trajectory, or the planning will more possible to fail to generate an uncollision trajectory?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181947/what-will-cause-when-collision-check-sampling-rate-set-too-low?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That number only affects the wizard -- once generated, it is never used again -- thus, the easy answer is "don't change it" since it won't improve performance in anything except the wizard (which is hopefully a one time thing)

For a better understanding of what is going on, that sampling basically helps decide which links should not be collision checked later on (and this information is put in the exported SRDF). For instance, two links that are adjacent and always touch cannot be checked for collision or all plans would fail to be collision free. The wizard may also be able to determine when two links are never in contact, because they are always too far apart, and thus there is no reason to collision check those joints as the result will always be false.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-07-02**:
Thank you~After the test, I found that if the rate is too low, it will more likely to output: No motion plan found. No execution attempted , then PR2 will not execute anything~